# Qual a diferença entre a saida do utils::URLencode() no R e o urllib.parse.quote() em Python

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Queria entender a diferença entre a saida do `utils::URLencode()` no R e o `urllib.parse.quote()` em Python, por exemplo:

Em R:

```r
tster <- '{"yearStart":"2020",\n"yearEnd":"2020",\n"typeForm":1}'
utils::URLencode(tster)
```

Output:

```
'%7B%22yearStart%22:%222020%22,%0A%22yearEnd%22:%222020%22,%0A%22typeForm%22:1%7D'
```

Em Python:

```python
import urllib

tster = '{"yearStart":"2020",\n"yearEnd":"2020",\n"typeForm":1}'

result_py = urllib.parse.quote(tster, encoding = 'utf-8')
result_py
```

Output:

```
'%7B%22yearStart%22%3A%222020%22%2C%0A%22yearEnd%22%3A%222020%22%2C%0A%22typeForm%22%3A1%7D'
```

A diferença neste caso pode ser resolvida com, que deixa a saída no Python igual ao do R:

```python
result_py.replace('%3A',':').replace('%2C',',')
```

Output:

```
'%7B%22yearStart%22:%222020%22,%0A%22yearEnd%22:%222020%22,%0A%22typeForm%22:1%7D'
```

Mas para strings maiores, além de feio fica muito trabalhoso. Como fazer para termos a saída do Python igual a do R?

Deixei os dois códigos para comparação nos links:

Em R:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oj-GCCUX4MZB_jW942DBMny-kN1sXdvy?usp=sharing

Em Python:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jpo9GrcTrFNidIdQih3PkLMR88t690kZ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esses caracteres `,` e `:` de seu exemplo tratam-se de caracteres reservados que, de acordo com a própria [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/URLencode) são preservados. Destacando o trecho relevante:

> In addition, ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; = : / ? @ # [ ] are reserved characters, and should be encoded unless used in their reserved sense, which is scheme specific. The default in URLencode is to leave them alone, which is appropriate for file:// URLs, but probably not for http:// ones.

Ou seja, esses caracteres são classificados como reservados de acordo com a especificação da [Internet STD 66](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66) (antiga **RFC3986**) e o padrão utilizado na função `utils::URLencode` é ignorar essa codificação incondicionalmente.

Caso você deseje reverter esse comportamento, basta sobrescrever o valor padrão do parâmetro `reserved` desta forma:

```r
utils::URLencode(tster, reserved = TRUE)
```

Com isso o resultado deve ser apresentado conforme o que é mostrado no Python 3; um detalhe adicional é que no caso deste último, é possível utilizar o parâmetro `safe` da função `urllib.parse.quote` para especificar os caracteres que — além dos *unreserved* caracteres alfanuméricos, `-`, `_`, `.` e `~` — não devem ser codificados, conforme descrito nesta parte do `help`:

> `quote(string, safe='/', encoding=None, errors=None)`
>
> *(...)*
>
> The quote function %-escapes all characters that are neither in the unreserved chars ("always safe") nor the additional chars set via the safe arg.
>
> *(...)*

Adicionando os caracteres do seu exemplo — além do padrão `/`　—, você consegue reproduzir o resultado do R:

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote(tster, encoding = 'utf-8', safe='/,:')
'%7B%22yearStart%22:%222020%22,%0A%22yearEnd%22:%222020%22,%0A%22typeForm%22:1%7D'
```